# C# HostedService through IHost - get Instance from running ServicePool

Tags: dependency-injection, microservices, background-service, ihostedservice

The question is quite simple, yet challenging.

Normal service creation:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                                {
                                    services.AddHostedService<WorkerA>();
                                    services.AddHostedService<WorkerB>();
                                })
                                .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Now, is it possible for WorkerB to get the "Instance" of WorkerA to Execute a Method, retrieve a properties, etc. ?
Yet, is there a "global" ServiceCollection or Servicepool to query on and retrieve the instances of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, WorkerA>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, WorkerB>();
```

Now `WorkerB` can be injected with `WorkerA` in its constructor, while its guaranteed that `WorkerB` gets the same instance as ASP.NET Core is using as a hosted service.

A better solution, though, is to extract the *shared logic* that is both used by `WorkerA` and `WorkerB` from `WorkerA` into a new service, and inject that into both `WorkerA` and `WorkerB`.

Do note that both workers might access the same logic in parallel, so you need to make sure that this shared code is thread safe.